# Is Socket.close() considered a clean way to end the connection?

Tags: java, sockets

As the title says - if I want to close a socket connection is it enough if I just call `mySocket.close()`? What will happen on the other side?

Or, if it's not the way to go, what is? Do I have to send some kind of "finish" message through the socket so the other side knows it should end as well?

Bonus question: java documentations says

> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.

So is closing the socket alone enough or do I have to explicitly close the streams as well (assuming I'm not using `try-with-resources`, of course)?

Answer (score 5):

Closing the socket won't do any thing on the other side. The remote host will not know that the connection has been closed.
The only way to check whether the connection is closed is to try to read or write from/to the input/output stream. If `-1` is returned by the `InputStream#read()` method, then the second side knows that the first side closed the connection. A thrown `IOException` also indicates a closed connection.

Normally you don't need to close the in/output stream as they are closed when invoking `Socket#close()`. `Socket#close()` is the only thing you need to do to close a connection.

But if you have a wrapper stream (e.g. `BufferdInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream`) you should explicitly close these wrapper streams to release resources used by these wrapper streams (e.g. byte buffer array). You only need to close the top level wrapper stream as closing the wrapper closes the wrapped stream which closes the wrapped stream of the wrapped stream, too. And so on...

Comment: That definitely answers my bonus question and thank you for that. But it doesn't answer my main question.

Comment: So to summarize: `Socket.close()` **is** the clean way to go but I **also** need to take care of things on the other side (check for `-1`/Exception and handle it, calling `Socket.close()` there as well). If I'm using stream wrappers I need to explicitly close them first as well. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to close the socket on the other side. But if you use wrapper streams on the other side, you should close them too, to release used resources. Check for -1/Exception is only required if you want to check whether the connection is closed (for other operations you want to do with the socket, or to close the wrapper streams).

Comment: Actually reading from the socket will block the thread until it receives some data or the timeout occurs. I've found that the way to go is to try to write to the socket. It immadiatelly throws the IOException if the client has closed the connection. This exception can be caught and handled properly.

Comment: Do we also need to close DataOutputStream?

Comment: DataOutputStream is a wrapper stream. Closing it will close the wrapped OutputStream as well. Since a DataoutputStream does not allocate any ressources, you don't have to close it. Closing the wrapped stream is sufficient. Nevertheless, it is a good practice to close the outermost stream.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.close()` is a clean way to close the connection. It causes a TCP FIN packet to be sent to the peer and starts the normal TCP shutdown sequence.

It also closes the socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, I don't see any ambiguity in the documentation on that point.

Comment: The documentation states it explicitly but at the same time I saw example codes where people closed stream wrappers manually. J. Tennié's answer exaplains why that is and that's exactly what I was missing here. That's why I asked the bonus question.